# Evaluation of ldaseqmodel in gensim

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, lda

is there a possibility to evaluate the dynamic model (ldaseqmodel) like the "normal" lda model in values of perplexity and topic coherence?
I know that these values are printed into the logging.INFO, so another method would be to save the logging.INFO into a text file to search for these evaluation values after the simulation.
If method 1 (code to evaluate ldaseqmodel) doesnt exist, is it possible to save the logging.INFO into a text file?
Here is my code to generate the ldaseqmodel:

```
from gensim import models, corpora
import csv
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

Anzahl_Topics1      = 10                

Zeitabschnitte      = [16, 19, 44, 51, 84, 122, 216, 290, 385, 441, 477, 375, 390, 408, 428, 192, 38]

TDM_dateipfad = './1gramm/TDM_1gramm_1998_2014.csv'

dateiname_corpus = "./1gramm/corpus_DTM_1gramm.mm"

dateiname1_dtm  = "./1gramm/DTM_1gramm_10.model"

ids = {} 
corpus = [] 

with open(TDM_dateipfad, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|') 
    for rownumber, row in enumerate(reader): 
        for index, field in enumerate(row):
            if index == 0:
                if rownumber > 0:
                    ids[rownumber-1] = field 
            else:
                if rownumber == 0:
                    corpus.append([])
                else:
                    corpus[index-1].append((rownumber-1, int(field))) 

corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(dateiname_corpus, corpus)

dtm1 = models.ldaseqmodel.LdaSeqModel(corpus=corpus, time_slice = Zeitabschnitte, id2word=ids, num_topics = Anzahl_Topics1, passes=1, chunksize=10000) 
dtm1.save(dateiname1_dtm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking two very different questions.

**Is it possible to save the logging.INFO into a text file?**

Yes. You can use this code to send your log to a file instead of the console. DEBUG level logging gives you more detailed information than INFO.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, file='yourlogname.log')
```

You might also want to set up file handlers to have an INFO log in the console, and a DEBUG level log to a file. See the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) for more info.

**Is there a possibility to evaluate the DTM using perplexity and topic coherence?**

Yes, use `dtm_coherence` - see the [gensim documentation here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.html) - coherence is generally a more useful measure (in terms of "do humans understand this") than perplexity. You will have to do so for each time slice separately though. My recommendation, if you want to compare two models, say a 10- vs. 20-topic model, would be to loop over the time slices for each model, and graph the coherence scores to see if one is consistently better, for example. There is a nice tutorial in this [DTM example from the gensim devs](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/ldaseqmodel.ipynb).

Comment: Do you have any code references for looping over the time slices for each model, and graphing the coherence scores? If there are 5 time slices, I'd assume there'd be 5 graphs each showing how the coherence has changed for each time slice?. But even then, what if the score for slice 1 is better with 10 topics whereas the score for topic 2 is better with 20 topics?

Comment: See the bottom of the example I linked at the end of my post. You would have to make one graph per model (i.e. one for a model for 10 topics, and another for a model with 20) based on the coherence values for each time slice. Model selection is tricky. I dont think there is a hard rule, you could see which is better on average? Always look at the content of the topics though.

Comment: I did check out the post but it just talks about one time slice, and not about comparing different models. Could you please answer to my question [here](https://groups.google.com/g/gensim/c/G8Tr9TfrP6Y) or [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/3369)? I have mixed results and from what you mentioned, I don't think I can treat the slices as independent entities, right?

Comment: My apologies, I do not entirely follow. I would recommend posting a new question with example code and a detailed description of the problem.